# Memory leak in Spark Driver

Tags: apache-spark

I used Spark 2.1.1 and I upgraded into the latest version 2.4.4. I observed from Spark UI that the driver memory is **increasing continuously** and after of long running I had the following error: **java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded**

In Spark 2.1.1 the driver memory consumption (Storage Memory tab) was extremely low and after the run of ContextCleaner and BlockManager the memory was decreasing.

Also, I tested the Spark versions 2.3.3, 2.4.3 and I had the same behavior.

**HOW TO REPRODUCE THIS BEHAVIOR:**

Create a very simple application(streaming count_file.py) in order to reproduce this behavior. This application reads CSV files from a directory, count the rows and then remove the processed files.

```
import os

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

target_dir = "..."

spark=SparkSession.builder.appName("DataframeCount").getOrCreate()

while True:
    for f in os.listdir(target_dir):
        df = spark.read.load(f, format="csv")
        print("Number of records: {0}".format(df.count()))

        os.remove(f)
        print("File {0} removed successfully!".format(f))
```

Submit code:

```
spark-submit 
--master spark://xxx.xxx.xx.xxx
--deploy-mode client
--executor-memory 4g
--executor-cores 3
--queue streaming count_file.py
```

**TESTED CASES WITH THE SAME BEHAVIOUR:**

- I tested with default settings (spark-defaults.conf)
- Add spark.cleaner.periodicGC.interval 1min (or less)
- Turn spark.cleaner.referenceTracking.blocking=false
- Run the application in cluster mode
- Increase/decrease the resources of the executors and driver
- I tested with extraJavaOptions in driver and executor -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=35 -XX:ConcGCThreads=12

**DEPENDENCIES**

- Operation system: Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
- Java: jdk1.8.0_131 (tested also with jdk1.8.0_221)
- Python: Python 2.7.12

Comment: how large is the csv file?   from your info, I didn't see you set the driver-memory this argument.

Comment: @DennisLi I have the described behavior independently with the size of the CSV or with driver memory. I tested with small CSVs (2-3M) and with larger CSVs (200-300M) and with different driver memory (1G -15G). 

In the given code, the spark uses the default driver memory 1G

Comment: I think you need to set the driver-memory argument with spark-submit. spark-submit --driver-memory 10g for example.

Comment: @DennisLi  You can set the driver memory wither in Spark submit or in spark-defaults.conf, I have set it in the spark-defaults.conf, but this is not relevant with the problem.

Comment: Have you solve this problem I'm facing similar issue

Comment: Hi @YumlembamRahul! I have created also a story with the above behavior in the Spark Jira. Finally, the increasing of the memory in the Spark UI was a bug, it was not an actual memory increase (https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29055)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the increase of the memory in Spark UI was a bug in Spark version higher than *2.3.3*. There is a fix. 
It will affect the Spark version *2.4.5+*.

Spark related issues:

- **Spark UI storage memory increasing overtime:** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29055
- **Possible memory leak in Spark:** https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-29321?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel